# Я не могу понять, return (x % 2) == 0; зачем там 0?

Tags: c++

Есть задача на нахождение четного/нечетного числа.
Но я не могу понять, return (x % 2) == 0; зачем там 0?

```
bool isEven(int x)
{
    // Если x % 2 == 0, то x - чётное число
    return (x % 2) == 0;
}


int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    cout << "Введи число ";
    int x;
    cin >> x;

    if (isEven(x))
        cout << x << " Четное\n";
    else
        cout << x << " Нечетное\n"; 

    введите сюда код

}
```

Comment: Даже зная про `!(x % 2)`, можно писать `(x % 2) == 0` т.к. это просто более очевидно.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ну, ведь остаток от деления четного числа на 2 равен 0...

```
bool isEven(int x)
{
    // Если x % 2 == 0, то x - чётное число
    return (x % 2) == 0;
}
```

Если вы вернете просто

```
bool isEven(int x)
{
    // Если x % 2 == 0, то x - чётное число
    return x % 2;
}
```

то `true` будет при **нечетном** значении. Например, при `x==3` значение `x%2 == 3%2 == 1`...

Конечно, можно еще и так:

```
bool isEven(int x)
{
    // Если x % 2 == 0, то x - чётное число
    return !(x % 2);
}
```